# How does tokenization work when there are unclosed tags during the DOM building step?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, dom, safari

So, during the DOM building step when the tokenizer is creating tokens from HTML document. How does it handle unclosed tags?

Let's say I have the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div>
  <h2>World</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

How does the `<div>` will be handle by the tokenizer?

It's there a standard for every browser to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a standard. [Section 8.2 of the HTML5 specification](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#parsing-html-documents) covers this.

But it depends on the elements that are unclosed. Sometimes elements are just closed automatically when other tags are encountered. In other cases, elements are closed and then reopened after the out-of-sequence tag. And in other cases, tags may be ignored completely.

In the specific case, you provide, the div element is created and added to the DOM as a child of the body element when the start element is encountered. The H2 element is created and becomes a child of the div element. The missing close div tag has no effect, the close body and close html tags do not change the DOM and then [parsing stops](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#the-end).

The close body tag will indicate that a [parse error](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#parse-errors) has occurred, but browsers don't usually do anything if a parse error is detected.

(Note that missing tags are issues for tree construction, and not the tokenizer.)